# index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection. parameter name: index

Tags: c#

Guys I really need for your help.  I am getting an error for the above title.    All trying to do is when datagridview is click it should display selected record into the text box as well as open it new form. Here is my code.

```
using System.Data;    
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace DataGridview
    {
        public partial class FrmDataGrid : Form
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
            public FrmDataGrid()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void FrmDataGrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UserData";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["UserID"].Value.ToString();
                    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[1].Cells["FullName"].Value.ToString();
                    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[2].Cells["Username"].Value.ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[3].Cells["UserPassword"].Value.ToString();
                    textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[4].Cells["UserRole"].Value.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                FrmUpdate FormUpdate = new FrmUpdate();
                FormUpdate.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read the error message and use your debugger. It's telling you you are asking for an element of a collection which doesn't exist. The most likely culprit is one of these lines: `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]`. You likely don't have 5 rows selected when clicking the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to fetch 5 rows without even checking that 5 rows exists in the result of your db query. I think you're trying to fetch 5 columns of a row, so use the following code for your requirement:

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["UserID"].Value.ToString();
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["FullName"].Value.ToString();
textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Username"].Value.ToString();
textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["UserPassword"].Value.ToString();
textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["UserRole"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I just figured out and your answer is correct. I do appreciate for your kind help.  But how can I send those data into a new form?

Comment: Could you please help me for the above code.  When I click data grid view cell I want it to open a new form with selected record?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely selecting a row that is out of range, during one of these calls:
`dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]`